# imagecreatefromjpeg is silently terminating scripts

Tags: php, gd, thumbnails

Like so many before me, I'm writing a PHP script to do some image thumbnailing. The script has earned WOMM (works on my machine) certification, but when I move it to my host (1&1 Basic), there's an issue: images above a certain filesize cannot be processed. I've moved all operations to the filesystem, to be certain it's not some latent `POST` issue. Here's the relevant code:

```
function cropAndResizeImage( $imageLocation )
{
  //
  // Just to be certain
  //
  ini_set('display_errors','on');
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('memory_limit','128M'); 
  ini_set('max_execution_time','300');  

  $image_info   = getimagesize($imageLocation);
  $image_width  = $image_info[0];
  $image_height = $image_info[1];
  $image_type   = $image_info[2];

  switch ( $image_type )
  {
    // snip...
    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
      $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageLocation);
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }

  // snip...
}
```

Using my mystical powers of `println` debugging, I've been able to determine that `imagecreatefromjpeg` is not returning; in fact, the script halts completely when it gets to it. Some facts:

- This is correlated to filesize. Images under 1MB appear to be fine (spot-checked), but images around 3MB barf. No clue what the precise cutoff is, though.
- This is not due to server timeouts; `wget` returns in <1s on 3MB images, significantly longer on "appropriately small" images (indicating no processing of large images).
- Prefixing the function call with `@` to suppress errors has no effect. This matches well with the fact that the script is not throwing an error, it's simply silently terminating upon this function call.

If I had to guess, there may be some GD parameter that I don't know about (or have access to) that limits input file sizes on 1&1's servers — the config variable guess is due to the fact that it barfs immediately, and doesn't appear (heuristically) to do any actual loading of or computations on the image.

Any suggestions? Thanks for the help.

**Update (courtesy [@Darryl's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5441/darryl-hein) comments):** calls to `phpinfo` indicate that PHP is updating the `max_execution_time` and `memory_limit` variables correctly. This doesn't necessarily mean that these resources are being allocated, simply that they appear to be functioning as expected.

**Update 2:** following some references from The Google, I tried optimizing the JPEG (reduced in quality from 3MB to 200KB) with no luck, so it's not an image filesize issue. I then tried reducing the number of pixels of the original 3888x2592 image, and the first successful size is 1400x2592 (1401x and 1402x both result in half-parses and errors indicating "malformed JPEG", which doesn't make much sense unless the entire image isn't being loaded). By reducing further to 1300x2592, I can instantiate the 400x300 thumbnail image that I'm actually looking for; at 1400x2592, the `imagecreatetruecolor` call I'm using to take care of that task fails silently in the same manner as `imagecreatefromjpeg`.

As to why this is, I'm a little uncertain. 1400 * 2592 == 3.5MB gives nothing particularly meaningful, but I have to imagine this is a limit on the number of pixels GD + PHP will process.

Answer (score 2):

Please see [this note](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php#76968) regarding memory usage on the php website.

*"The memory required to load an image using imagecreatefromjpeg() is a function of the image's dimensions and the images's bit depth, multipled by an overhead.

It can calculated from this formula:

Num bytes = Width * Height * Bytes per pixel * Overhead fudge factor"*

Comment: Hi JC-- when I lower the memory allocation to 1M and use a smaller image, I get this error: "
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1048576 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in /homepages/17/d203907073/htdocs/d-i-s/dev/inc/image.functions.php on line 98" (...continued...)

Comment: (...continued...) Because the server is correctly throwing "out of memory" errors in this case, I'm guessing it's a different cause, as in my case no errors are thrown. At any rate, the 3MB image is roughly 3Kx3K pixels, which translates to roughly 70MB with alpha and 2x fudge factor.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing 1&1 doesn't allow you to change scripts `memory_limit` or `max_execution_time`, so it's probably running out of memory. Have you tried running `phpinfo()` to see what the limits are?

Comment: Hey Darryl-- I was actually surprised to figure this out, but 1&1 *appears* to allow setting these parameters. At least, when I set them and run phpinfo(), it all shows up as expected. Is it possible they've got a secondary enforcement system?